# Get duration of video with AVFoundation

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, avfoundation, avplayer

To get the duration of an `AVPlayerItem` I could do: `player.currentItem.duration`.

Instead of this, I could also get the duration from my backend as an `Int`. Then I can convert this to a `Float` to be used anywhere I need the duration for. I think this might be better in terms of performance and less work on my end to get the duration.

*For example Apple says this about getting duration:*

> “A vital concept in AV Foundation is that initializing an asset or a
>   track does not necessarily mean that it is ready for use. It may
>   require some time to calculate even the duration of an item (an MP3
>   file, for example, may not contain summary information). Rather than
>   blocking the current thread while a value is being calculated, you ask
>   for values and get an answer back asynchronously through a callback
>   that you define using a block.”

Any thoughts on things that could go wrong if I decide to hardcode the duration by getting it from the server? Is this good practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already know the value on your backend, and you're already making call to say get the video URL, retrieving the duration seems a reasonable idea.

Although - is there any chance of a mismatch? If you do it client side it's "guaranteed" to be correct.

If you have to make a special call to get it, I wouldn't as it's likely to take much longer than determining it during asset initialisation.

Comment: Just to confirm: All of the data for the video comes in just 1 api call, it returns JSON with all the data needed such as video title, duration, description, etc. Based on what you said then, using the JSON data that has the duration in it is better than getting it from `player.currentItem.duration`?

Comment: Yes, in that case I'd definitely use your pre-calculated duration.

Comment: Ok thank you for taking the time to clarify this! : )